# iOS Core Data - Relationships

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, core-data

I’m guessing this is a basic question and hopefully someone will be able to point me in the right direction to some sample code, so my question….

I want/have created a core data model that has a parent child relationship, one to many, what I would like to know is what is the correct way to insert child records if the parent already exists.  What I’m struggling to understand is how the parent relationship is created when only inserting child records.

Hopefully this makes sense, thanks for any help.

Answer (score 14):

Here You have a series of 3 tutorials: [RayWenderlich: Core Data Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started)

Here a sample app: [iPhoneCoreDataRecipes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008913) with a more complex data model

Here a [Core Data tutorial – One to Many Relationship](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/09/29/iphone-app-development-tutorial-core-data-part-2-one-to-many-relationship/)

Sorry I not respond to your question in his totally. I'm also starting with Core Data, so If You find a good intermediate tuturial, please let me know.

**EDIT:**
A nice article: [Core Data Class Overview](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000086.php)

Comment: I advise not to follow Ray Wenderlich's tutorial. He goes to some Python script implementation in Core Data which will completely confuse new learner..

Comment: I generally advise Ray's tutorials, but his ones related to Core Data are particularly confusing...

Answer (score 3):

So you'll have Parent and Child. Child will contain a Parent *parentobject while Parent will contain a NSSet *children. Whenever you set the relationship correct in the Datamodel the relationship will be applied automatically when you fill the children set with Child objects.

Please check [Articles here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdRelationships.html)